# what's the purpose of using run following a main class on the java command line?

Tags: java

I am seeing some code are started like

```
java MainClass run -cp ******
```

I have two questions here,

1. why using run
2. why specify another classpath following run, any reason or benefit?

Answer (score 6):

1. In your example, "run" is only an argument of the program, not the JVM. It is not a keyword or anything. The program will simply be passed it as a String.
2. The -cp argument seems to be also an argument to the program.

From the look of the command line, I guess the MainClass program is used to run another class, which is looked for in the classpath defined by the -cp argument. So, neither "run" nor "-cp ..." are actually used by the VM to run MainClass, but by MainClass itself to run another program.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I added the second part of my answer a bit later, as I felt I had not answered the question with enough precision.

Answer (score 1):

`run`, `-cp`, and `******` will be passed as arguments to the `main` function in the *java class* `MainClass`.

Anything on the command-line, after the class name, are arguments to the class, not arguments to the `java` VM.